# Spring WebClient automatically adding value to url

Tags: java, spring-mvc, youtube-api, spring-webclient

I'm new in spring.

I'm trying to get data from youtube's api using webclient

My service layer look like this

```
@Service
public class YoutubeService implements YTB {
private WebClient webClient;

private final String API_KEY="";

public YoutubeService() {
    webClient=WebClient.create("https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/");
}

public YoutubeService(WebClient webClient) {
    this.webClient = webClient;
}

public List<youtubeData> getData(String id){
   
    return webClient.get()
            .uri("/videos?part=snippet%2Cstatistics&id="+id+"&key="+API_KEY)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(youtubeData.class)
            .collectList()
            .block();
}
}
```

And my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ytbapi")
public class ytbController {

@Autowired
private YTB service;

@GetMapping("/getData/{id}")
public List<youtubeData> show(@PathVariable String id){
    return service.getData(id);
}
}
```

It work fine when I set

```
uri("/videos?part=snippet&id="+id+"&key="+API_KEY")
```

But when I change it to like above and run, I got HTTP Status 500

> Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$BadRequest:
> 400 Bad Request from GET
> https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%252Cstatistics&id=r9LqfLM93Hw&key=AIzaSyDpPf8w8YN4O6KSiedVUwusiPhU-HP4Iek

The problem is something add 25 in this part: `snippet%252Cstatistics`

How should I fix it?

Comment: Please renew your YouTube Data API v3 key as you just leaked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your URI string `"/videos?part=snippet%2Cstatistics&id="+id+"&key="+API_KEY` you have a character "%" which has a so called reserved meaning.
`uri(String uri, Object... uriVariables)` method of `UriSpec` class uses `DefaultUriBuilderFactory` [by default under the hood](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-webflux/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/DefaultWebClient.java#L219), which uses `UriComponentsBuilder`'s `encode()` method [by default](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/util/DefaultUriBuilderFactory.java#L251). So, **symbol *"%"* is encoded to *"%25"*** in your URI.

You can check what symbols are encoded and to what [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

You used *"%2C"* in your URI, so I believe you meant "," there.
As URL-encoding is the default behavior of `WebClient`, you can define you uri path in unencoded way with a simple coma like this:

```
.uri("/videos?part=snippet,statistics&id="+id+"&key="+API_KEY)
```

Comment: @KienNguyen happy to help! please rate my answer and mark it as a correct one